# MODULE_NOT_FOUND when using npm

Tags: npm, astrojs

I just ran npm run dev and I got this error while using Astro (fresh install, no edits):

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\project1\web\v2> npm run dev      

> dev
> astro dev

'project1\web\v2\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\astro\astro.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.18.0
```

I am an amateur so apologies if the answer is simple.

Thanks a lot

I have tried some npm commands but nothing has helped.

Comment: I have tried adding "code": "node ./node_modules/lib/index.js" to "scripts". I really have no idea... Please help!

Answer (score 0):

There was the special character "&" in a folder name which was a parent folder of the Astro project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ok I will do that.